# Powershell script to check all my AD computers BIOS versions and export to excel sheet

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

**I created below test script to run on Power shell. What I wanted firstly check computer on AD and then get the BIOS version from that particular PC.
Below is my sample code,**

```
$arrADcomp = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase " OU=Prod,OU=Workstations,OU=CCCSOE,DC=XXX,DC=com").Name
$arrRtn=@()

foreach ($chkBIOS in $arrADcomp)
{
$BIOSinfo = @{}
$BIOSinfo.Asset_Tag = $chkBIOS
$arrRtn += new-object -typename psobject -property $chkBIOS
}


$arrRtn | Select-Object Asset_Tag | Out-File C:\Powershell\computer1.csv
```

**Unfortunately I am getting below error. I am new to powershell and I have no idea about how to solve this**

```
New-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Property'. Cannot convert the "LT9JL5N32" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:8 char:56
+     $arrRtn += new-object -typename psobject -property $chkBIOS
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Comment: Looks like it should be `-property $BIOSinfo`

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the TessellatingHeckler's comment,

Replace:

```
$arrRtn += new-object -typename psobject -property $chkBIOS
```

With:

```
$arrRtn += new-object -typename psobject -property $BIOSinfo
```

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciable